# Oracle-00972 : identifier too long what's wrong with my SQL?

Tags: php, sql, oracle

```
<?php

// This leaves the db connection in $conng require_once('/tms/http/html_docs/tease/csp/csp_tease.php');

    /* This a logging function. When called with:
     */

    function log_tkt_to_db($tkt_number, $date, $uid, $description, $conng)
    {
        echo "$tkt_number|$date|$uid|$description<br>";

        $sqlinsert = "insert into TEASE_TKTLOGS  VALUES ( \"$tkt_number\", \"$date\", \"$description\",  \"$uid\")";
        echo $sqlinsert . "<br>";
        $insert = OCIParse($conng, $sqlinsert);
        // OCIExecute($insert, OCI_COMMIT_ON_SUCCESS);
        OCIExecute($insert);
    }

log_tkt_to_db("00000000", "07/13/2012", "jt898u", "this a test, this is only a test", $conng);
?>
```

I get this output:

```
00000000|07/13/2012|jt898u|this a test, this is only a test
insert into TEASE_TKTLOGS (TICKET, DATE_TIME, CHANGE_DESC, ATTUID) VALUES ( "00000000", "07/13/2012", "this a test, this is only a test", "jt898u")

Warning: ociexecute() [function.ociexecute]: ORA-00972: identifier is too long in /appl/tms/http/html_docs/tease/dblog.php on line 17
```

Comment: Take a look at this for some reasons resulting in this error: http://www.coderanch.com/t/80098/Oracle-OAS/ORA-identifier-too-long-at

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are multiple things wrong here.

1. The simplest answer is that you need to use single quote marks (`'`) instead of double quotes (see *String Literals* in [Oracle Database SQL Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#i42617))
2. You really should use something like [`oci_bind_by_name`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-bind-by-name.php) instead of blindly inserting your values into the query. Saves you a parse and a potential SQL injection.
3. [`ociparse`](http://ee.php.net/manual/en/function.ociparse.php) and [`ociexecute`](http://ee.php.net/manual/en/function.ociexecute.php) are deprecated as of PHP 5.4. Instead of these you should use, respectively, `oci_parse` and `oci_execute`.

Comment: 1) I later found http://www.coderanch.com/t/80098/Oracle-OAS/ORA-identifier-too-long-at which mentions that the error message due to quoting.

Comment: 3) Legacy installation/code. The `PHP` is at 5.2.4. All the existing code uses `ociparse()` so I did too.